# Intent from fragment to activity looping?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have problem, i click one of my listview (18 List) in fragment then i go to activity from the list, but when i pressed back button, it didnt go to fragment, i need to pressed it few times equals the amount of my list.

This my fragment

```
public class LightMenu extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Database db;
    ArrayList<Record_Cibse>listCibse;
    String [] LightMenu = {"Lux Level Recomendation", "Color Temperature", "Types of Lamps", "Lamp's Properties" +
            "", "What's in a Ballast", "Magnetic vs Electronic Ballast", "Ballast Connections", "Types of Celling" +
            "", "Reflectane Factors Chart", "Utilization Factor Table", "Efficacy of Fluorescent Lamp Sys 1" +
            "", "Efficacy of Fluorescent Lamp Sys 2", "One Gang / One Way Switch", "Two Gang / One-Way Switch" +
            "", "Three Gang / One Way Switch", "Simple Autocad Design", "Enclosure (Protection)", "Index Protection (1st Numeral)" +
            "", "Index Protection (2nd Numeral)"};
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.light_menu,null);
        db=new Database(getActivity());
        listCibse=db.getAllCibse();

    list = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < LightMenu.length; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("listview_title", LightMenu[i]);

        hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(R.mipmap.ic_logo_menu ));
        list.add(hm);
    }
    String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title"};
    int[] to = {R.id.listview_image_convert,R.id.listview_item_conversion};

    LinearLayout Lin = (LinearLayout)x.findViewById(R.id.LinLayout);


    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),list,R.layout.one_text_listview,from,to);

    listView = (ListView)x.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18;
            int position= i;
            String menu = LightMenu[i];
            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    a0  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a0.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a0);
                case 1 :
                    a1  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a1.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a1);
                case 2 :
                    a2  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a2.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a2);
                case 3 :
                    a3  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a3.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a3);
                case 4 :
                    a4  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a4.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a4);
                case 5 :
                    a5  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a5.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a5);
                case 6 :
                    a6  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a6.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a6);
                case 7 :
                    a7  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a7.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a7);
                case 8 :
                    a8  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a8.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a8);
                case 9 :
                    a9  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a9.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a9);
                case 10 :
                    a10  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a10.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a10);
                case 11 :
                    a11  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a11.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a11);
                case 12 :
                    a12  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a12.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a12);
                case 13 :
                    a13  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a13.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a13);
                case 14 :
                    a14  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a14.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a14);
                case 15 :
                    a15  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a15.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a15);
                case 16 :
                    a16  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a16.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a16);
                case 17 :
                    a17  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a17.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a17);
                case 18 :
                    a18  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
                    a18.putExtra("menu",menu);
                    startActivity(a18);

            }
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    return x;
}
```

}

This my Activity class

```
public class Recommendation extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Database db;
    ArrayList<Record_Cibse>listCibse;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recommendation);

//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        x.setTitle("Lux Level Recomendations");
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        TextView titleToolBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        titleToolBar.setSingleLine();
        titleToolBar.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        titleToolBar.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("menu"));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        db=new Database(this);
        listCibse=db.getAllCibse();

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listCibse.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("listview_title", listCibse.get(i).getLocation());

            hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            list.add(hm);
        }
        String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title"};
        int[] to = {R.id.listview_image_convert,R.id.listview_item_conversion};

        LinearLayout Lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinLayout);


        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.one_text_listview,from,to);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int id = listCibse.get(i).getId_cibse();
                String location = listCibse.get(i).getLocation();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),location,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent a  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RecommendationDetail.class);
                a.putExtra("id",id);
                a.putExtra("location",location);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
//        return x;
    }



    public void onBackPressed(){
        db.close();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No break in Switch cases

```
case 12 :
            a12  = new Intent(getActivity(),Recommendation.class);
            a12.putExtra("menu",menu);
            startActivity(a12);
            break;
case 13 :
```

Use break after every switch case else, all cases below the condition fulfilled will be processed